# Calling an arduino function through pyserial in python

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying get an ultrasonic reading from a sensor thats connected to an arduino and the function which runs that sensor is in the ardunio sketch however I want to be able to call that function through a python script when I need to ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

well its fairly simple.. first, you need *pyserial* library with proper setup (correct COM port and baud). Then in arduino in main function, add a code like:

```
int incoming;
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    incoming = Serial.read();
  }
  if(incoming == 1) {
    yourFunction();
  } else {
    errorFunction();
  }
}
```

expecting value "1" to be send from python script. If its sent and received by arduino, `yourFunction()` will be executed, otherwise `errorFunction()` will be. Change `if(incoming == 1)` to anything you want to.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful

Comment: How would I send the value 1 from python to arduino ? Is it using ".write()"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then in python, you just need to read serial port.

Comment: well if you take a look at arduino serial library, and look at _write_ function thay say:
_Writes binary data to the serial port. This data is sent as a byte or series of bytes; to send the characters representing the digits of a number use the print() function instead. _
so if you want to send a string/character (also number, if its parsed to char), use print. Number will be sent like : `Serial.print("7");`

Comment: does it matter if the serial.print() is in the function ? will it still send through once the function is run ?

Comment: also are you any good on the python side could you give me an example of how you would send the value "1" to the serial port and read the returning to see if i have done it write ?

Comment: Well i am not here to write code for you, and its actually written in rules of this page. I can provide you with sample code (not pseudocode), that you can refer to, but not today, i have some work.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful.